# Do not change frame number with allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

In beamer, I want to insert a bibliography but there are too many references to fit on one page. Hence I sue the option `allowframebreaks` to split it over many pages.
My issue is about the numbering of these pages : it sets a new number for each page, and I would like to have the same number for all of them, as if I had used `\only`.

Here is an ECM :

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hello world}
  \nocite{*}
  This is frame number 1.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with the bibliography `biblio.bib` :

```tex
@article{article1,
  author  = {article author 1},
  journal = {journal name 1},
  number  = {0},
  title   = {\lipsum[1]},
  volume  = {0},
  year    = {2023}
}

@article{article2,
  author  = {article author 2},
  journal = {journal name 2},
  number  = {0},
  title   = {\lipsum[2]},
  volume  = {0},
  year    = {2023}
}
```

This table shows the frame numbering I'd like to have on each page

| Pdf page | Numbering I get | Numbering I'd like to have |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (*Hello world*) | 1/3 | 1/2 |
| 2 (*Bibliography I*) | 2/3 | 2/2 |
| 3 (*Bibliography II*) | 3/3 | 2/2 |

Comment: Just a tip: biblatex comes with a sample bibliography `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`. Then you don't have to share two files in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `noframenumbering` option to switch off frame numbers and manually increase the counter before the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hello world}
  \nocite{*}
  \cite{knuth:ct}
  This is frame number 1.
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{1}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works well, thanks !

Comment: @Thomas You're welcome!